# Can a familiar translate for the owner?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, languages

For example, a sprite knows Elvish and Sylvan. Assuming the owner does not speak these languages themselves, would the sprite be able to translate for the owner? What about the pseudodragon which understands Draconic and has the "Limited Telepathy" feature?

Comment: Are you asking about all possible familiars or a specific kind of familiar such as the one you gain by casting the find familiar spell?

Comment: @Akixkisu That clarification is unnecessary—this question is not so broad that including all familiars is going to be a problem. Frankly, I strongly suspect the answer is the same for all of them anyway. There is no need to limit this question, or to explicitly state that it isn’t limited.

Comment: @KRyan the problem here is more that the source of the "familiar" is unclear. Familiar could entail, especially when asked by someone who isn't an expert in the system, various creatures that don't behave like familiars gained by the find familar spell - such as steeds from the find steed spell.

Comment: @Akixkisu Yes, it could arguably include those, though frankly that’s a stretch and I doubt voters would ding answers that didn’t. But either way, *that’s fine.* It’s OK that for querents to be unfamiliar with the breadth of the material and not realize there’s more out there that may affect things—answers addressing that and expanding their horizons is a **feature**, not a bug. This question can be answered as-is; it might be a somewhat larger question than the querent imagined, but it’s not too large. And since it can be answered as-is, it should not be closed.

Comment: @KRyan It would be great if the querent added those. For your information - I'm not voting to close.

Answer (score 6):

### Any creature can act as a translator

Under RAW, languages are binary: either a creature doesn’t  know a word or they are completely fluent and their vocabulary is 100% complete. If they know two languages, there is no reason that they cannot act as a perfect translator for two other creatures that know only one of those languages.

It doesn’t matter if the creature is a familiar or not.